# Loop over delegate

Tags: c#, events, delegates

I want to know how C# interprete that piece of code.

```
    public delegate void ChangeStateHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
    public event ChangeStateHandler ChangeStateEvent = delegate { };

    protected void OnChangeState(EventArgs e) {
        ChangeStateHandler ev = ChangeStateEvent;

        ev(this, e);   // <<<<< that LINE
    }
```

I know that is partial translated to:

```
private EventHandlerList events = new EventHandlerList();  
    private Object myeventObject = new object();  
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> myevent  
    {  
        add { events.AddHandler(myeventObject, value); }  
        remove { events.RemoveHandler(myeventObject, value); }  
    }
```

In the "reality" ev(this, e) how is translated?
I suppose something like:

```
ChangeStateHandler ev = ChangeStateEvent;
foreach (myHandler in ev) {
     myHandler(this, e);
}
```

But, how a single function ( ev ) can generate a loop? And how implement something like that?

Cheers

Comment: Are you essentially asking "What is the magic by which [Multicast Delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173175.aspx) can invoke the multiple handlers attached to them?" EDIT: And how can I roll my own Multicast Delegate or mimic similar behaviour?

Comment: It's hard to understand what are you asking for. If you want to know how's the generated CIL gonna look like, use decompiler for that.

Answer (score 2):

Close - it is *semantically* similar to:

```
foreach (ChangeStateHandler myHandler in ev.GetInvocationList()) {
     myHandler(this, e);
}
```

Comment: Perfectly! Is there a way to implement that "magic" in my code? call a function that auto-unbox my args and call the list of objects added?

Comment: @Kaiser69 I don't understand the question; that isn't magic - that is usable code

Comment: heh..English isn't my first language. The magic is relative to myHandler() that's transparently-translated to >>foreach ( bla bla)<< How to implement a function that implement that auto-translation? Something that I only call myFunction(myArgs) and loop over the items in the myFunction{}?